# Mysql and execute stored procedure in atomic way or select update atomically

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, database-concurrency

In Mysql I have two concurrent processes that need to read some rows and update a flag based on a condition.

I have to write a stored procedure with transaction but the problem is that sometimes the two processes updates the same rows.

I have a table `Status` and I want read 15 rows where the flag `Reserved` is true, then update those rows setting the flag `Reserved` to `False`.

The updated rows must be returned to the client.

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_reserved`()
BEGIN
DECLARE tmpProfilePageId bigint;
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE curProfilePage CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ProfilePageId 
    FROM Status
    WHERE Reserved is false and ((timestampdiff(HOUR, UpdatedTime, NOW()) >= 23) or UpdatedTime is NULL)
    ORDER BY UpdatedTime ASC
    LIMIT 15;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

START TRANSACTION;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TmpAdsProfile;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TmpAdsProfile(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ProfilePageId BIGINT);

OPEN curProfilePage;

getProfilePage: LOOP
    FETCH curProfilePage INTO tmpProfilePageId;
    IF finished = 1 THEN LEAVE getProfilePage;
    END IF;
    UPDATE StatusSET Reserved = true WHERE ProfilePageId = tmpProfilePageId;
    INSERT INTO TmpAdsProfile (ProfilePageId) VALUES (tmpProfilePageId);
END LOOP getProfilePage;

CLOSE curProfilePage;

SELECT ProfilePageId FROM TmpAdsProfile;

COMMIT;

END
```

Anyway, if I execute two concurrent processes that call this stored procedure, sometimes they update the same rows.

How can I execute the stored procedure in an atomic way?

Comment: You should call the stored procedure inside a transaction - and use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` to prevent the rows from being modified by a concurrent transaction.

Comment: Additionally - move all statements which does not need in transaction out of the transaction (temptable creation, final SELECT...).

Answer (score 0):

Simplify this a bit and use [`FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). That will lock the rows you want to change until you commit the transaction. You can get rid of the cursor entirely. Something like this, not debugged!

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TmpAdsProfile AS
SELECT ProfilePageId 
  FROM Status
 WHERE Reserved IS false 
   AND ((timestampdiff(HOUR, UpdatedTime, NOW()) >= 23) OR UpdatedTime IS NULL)
 ORDER BY UpdatedTime ASC
 LIMIT 15 
   FOR UPDATE; 

 UPDATE Status SET Reserved = true 
  WHERE ProfilePageId IN (SELECT ProfilePageId FROM TmpAdsProfile);
 
COMMIT;

SELECT ProfilePageId FROM TmpAdsProfile;
```

That temporary table will only ever have fifteen rows in it. So indexes and PKs and all that are not necessary. Therefore you can use `CREATE ... AS SELECT ...` to create and populate the table in one go.

And, consider recasting your UpdatedTime filter so it can use an index.

```
AND (UpdatedTime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 23 HOUR OR UpdatedTime IS NULL)
```

The appropriate index for the SELECT query is

```
CREATE INDEX status_update ON Status (Reserved, UpdatedTime, ProfilePageId);
```

The faster your SELECT operation can be, the less time your transaction will take, so the better your overall performance will be.